# Recorrer Items de un Listbox en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Tengo un Listbox llamado 'TablaKPIs' el cual solo contiene controles usercontrol de tipo 'KPIControl':

```
    <ListBox Name="TablaKPIs">


        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <uc:KPIControl/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


    </ListBox>
```

Para crear los controles, al Itemsource le asigno una lista que contiene objetos de tipo 'KPI'. El tipo 'KPI' es una clase que nada tiene que ver con el usercontrol 'KPIControl', pero dentro del KPIControl hago bindings a las propiedades del KPI...

```
TablaKPIs.ItemsSource = Tablas_BBDD.Lista_KPIs;
```

El caso es que yo necesito acceder a las propiedades de cada uno de los KPIControl, pero no se como hacerlo. Por ejemplo, cuando accedo al evento SelectionChanged, soy capaz de acceder al objeto KPI, pero no sé como acceder al objeto KPIControl que ha desencadenado el evento:

```
private void TablaKPIs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (TablaKPIs.SelectedItem != null)
     {
        //Capturamos el KPI seleccionado
        KPI KPI_Seleccionado = (KPI)TablaKPIs.SelectedItem;
     }
}
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, se lo agradecería muchisimo.
Gracias y un saludo!!

Comment: El objeto KPI que desencadeno el evento, es el que viene en el sender ;)

Comment: Toda la razon, por eso mismo, lo que busco, no es el objeto KPI, es el objeto KPIControl, que esta "dentro" del DataTemplate.

Comment: Y no estan aca??? KPI_Seleccionado ???

Comment: El objeto KPI_Seleccionado es de tipo KPI (el mismo tipo que los objetos almacenados en el ItemSource de la TablaKPIs), pero yo no busco acceder a ese objeto. Yo busco poder acceder a los objetos de tipo <uc:KPIControl/> que se crean gracias a definirlos en el DataTemplate. Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: No lo entiendo bien. Tu le pasas al itemsource objetos de tipo KPI, y en el selecteditem te devuelve eso mismo. Para que quieres acceder al user control?

Comment: Estoy igual que pikoh.. no termino de entender para que queres ver el control...

Comment: Porque el objeto KPI contiene información que se extrae de una base de datos, mientras que el objeto usercontrol es una representación gráfica de todos esos datos. Necesito acceder a ese usercontrol para poder controlar cosas como el color de fondo, los bordes, etc..

Comment: En ese caso lo mejor será que uses [`DataTriggers`](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/es/93/estilos/trigger-datatrigger-y-eventtrigger/) para que todas esas modificaciones del control se hagan automáticamente dependiendo de los datos que hay en el control. Esa es una de las ventajas de WPF sobre Winforms